# EV3 IR Beacon/Remote Programmability

Tags: mindstorms, ev3

Can the EV3 IR Beacon/Remote be programmed to emit other IR signals, like for triggering a camera?

I'd like to use the Mindstorms EV3 kit for building a hyperlapse photography rover where it moves, waits X seconds, triggers the camera, then repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the EV3 IR remote (which uses the same protocol as Power Functions remote) is not programmable. The simplest way of doing your timelapse photography is to press the button of your camera remote with a cam on an EV3 motor...